# Hex conversion in Perl

Tags: perl

I have to convert decimal values to hex.In my code code I am using

```
$hex = sprintf("0x%X", $temp);
```

But here the problem am facing is if the decimal value is `35`, then am getting hex value as `0x23`.But Ineed the out put as `0x023`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to add the `0x` part, and you can use zeros to justify:

```
sprintf "%#05x", 35;   # 0x023
```

Documentation [here.](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) Note that the "number of zeros" to justify is 5 here and not 3 as one might think.